# Generating pythagorean triples in this question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

> Find all integer solutions to $x^{2}+8xy+25y^{2}=225 \tag 1$

$(1)$ can be written as $$(x+4y)^2 + (3y)^2 = 15^2$$

This reduces the problem to a matter of generating pythagorean triples. I'm thinking that Euclid's method would be useful, but it's not immediately obvious to me how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the quadratic equation
$$x^2 + 8xy + 25y^2 - 225 = 0$$
where $x$ is the unknown. Compute
$$\frac{\Delta}{4} = 16y^2 - 25y^2 + 225 = 225 - 9 y^2.$$
Then $x$ is an integer if and only if the discriminant is a perfect square.

Notice that $9 \cdot 5^2 = 225 = 0$, therefore $-5 \le y \le 5$. Now check for which $y$ the discriminant is a perfect square, and then compute the solutions for both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: How do you arrive at the inequality from the observation that $9(5^2) = 225$?

Comment: If $\lvert y \rvert > 5$, then $225 - 9 y^2 < 225 - 9 \cdot 25 < 0$, and $\Delta < 0$ implies that the equation has no solutions for $x$.

Comment: Ah I see, this is really nice. Do you have any ideas on whether my approach is a dead end without brute force?

Comment: Looking at your equation $(x + 4y)^2 + (3y)^2 = 15^2$, you could still have obtained that $-5 \le y \le 5$. From then, I think brute force is necessary, but it's not that much of a burden since there are few values to check. In fact, my approach is almost the same as yours; I would say it's simply more mechanical.

Comment: How would I obtain the inequality from my approach?

Comment: From $15^2 - (3y)^2 = (x + 4y)^2 \ge 0$ you get $225 - 9y^2 \ge 0$, i.e. $y^2 \le 25$, i.e. $-5 \le y \le 5$.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Note that :-

$$15^2=9^2+12^2$$ is true.

So,$$(x+4y)^2+(3y)^2=9^2+12^2$$

Comment: More preferable than just an answer would be a method which I'd be able to apply in other scenarios.

Comment: @Airdish You cannot have a general brute force formula for solving all these types of question because this is a two variable equation but you only have one equation.Generally we need to have that many equations as the number of variables.For solving a $3$ variable equation,you would be provided with three equations which satisfy the same condition....so you must apply some intuition and trick...

Comment: Maybe there are solutions using $15^2+0^2$?  The danger in just finding something that works ad hoc is you miss other possibities.  I have mis-solved plenty of Sudoku puzzles by falling into that trap :-S .